# Access a Div inside a Div (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem with accessing a Div's attribute inside another Div.
I'm using the JQuery Plugin QuickFlip and want to change the background image
of the back.

```
<div class="quickFlip">
  <div class="blackPanel"> </div>
  <div class="redPanel">
    <p class="quickFlipCta">Click to Flip</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the structure of one of my panel. (I got more of them all with the same class name).
With this code I loaded one of the panels into the variable "div".

```
$(div).quickFlipper();

div = $(".quickFlip").get().sort(function(){ 
  return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,1);
```

Now I want to access the background image... I already tried this:

```
$(div).$('redPanel')({'background': 'url(tiles/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

which was actually not working... ^^
I was able to change the background of the quickFlip class with this code but not the background of the redpanel...

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Your jQuery selector should be `$('.redPanel')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use more local variables.

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length),
    bg = 'url(tiles/' + images[i] + ')';

$(div).find('div.redpanel').css('background-image', bg);
```